# Logback SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy is not rolling

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback, slf4j, rollingfileappender

I have this configurarion:

```
<appender name="ROLLIN" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${SCRIPTMON_HOME}/logs/scriptMon.log</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%thread] %logger{15} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${SCRIPTMON_HOME}/logs/scriptMon.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
        <minIndex>1</minIndex>
        <maxIndex>10</maxIndex>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
</appender>
```

IFAIK my logfile must rotate when it reaches 5MB (this is all I want regardless the date). I can in one run in Springboot achieve more than 10MB and the files stays the same.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing

```
<fileNamePattern>${SCRIPTMON_HOME}/logs/scriptMon.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
```

to

```
<fileNamePattern>${SCRIPTMON_HOME}/logs/scriptMon.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
```